# shift()の使い方について

Tags: python, pandas

python初心者です。よろしくお願いします。

下記は正常に動くのですが、

```
df['ud_flag'] = df.apply(lambda x : 1 if x.p == 1 else(-1 if x.p == -1 else 0),axis=1)
```

udのフラグとして、1又は-1の値のみにしたい。
つまり、udが0値の部分を、前回の1、又は-1のままとしたいので、下記のように修正するとエラーになります。

```
df['ud_flag'] = df.apply(lambda x : 1 if x.p == 1 else(-1 if x.p == -1 else x.p.shift(1)),axis=1)
```

エラー内容

```
AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'shift'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

データ

```
ud    ud_flag
0
0
1
0
0
-1
0
1
0
0
```

Comment: flagとして、1個前のフラグ値を使う場合は、shift(1)ではなく、何を使えばよいのでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

shift()は確か、配列に対して行、列をずらす関数です。
なので、int型には使えないと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

`shift()`じゃないですが、前方穴埋めのために一回マスクするとかどうでしょう。

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ud': '''0
0
1
0
0
-1
0
1
0
0'''.split('\n')})

df['ud_flag'] = df.mask(df['ud'] == '0').fillna(method='ffill') \
                                        .fillna('0')
```